# converting php string with date and time to sql timestamp

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a php string which contains the date and time as shown below

```
2015-05-27 18:45:31
```

How can I convert this to a type which I can insert into postgresql table with timestamp data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it using [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function:

```
$unix_timestamp=strtotime('2015-05-27 18:45:31');
```

Thes use `$unix_timestamp` in your SQL query.

Also you can use `TIMESTAMP '2015-05-27 18:45:31'` notation right in SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another format of date, you can use *DateTime::createFromFormat*

In your case:

```
$dateString = '2015-05-27 18:45:31';
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$dateConvert = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $dateString);
echo "Date: $format; " . $dateConvert->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

The output would be something like:

```
Date: Y-m-d H:i:s; 2015-05-27 18:45:31
```